# k-Fold cross-validation figure using TikZ or table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, diagrams

I am wondering how I can create a figure using a table or TikZ to depict the idea behind cross validation. Can anyone help me create something that looks something like the attached image?

[image: k-fold cross validation]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! What have you done so far?

Comment: Thanks! I haven't done anything yet, since I am uncertain where to start. I considered just making a table with borders and coloring the "holdout" cells (main diagonal), but I thought it would be easier to draw the legends etc using TikZ.

Comment: @EirikFosse legend could be easily done with a second `tabular` with both vertical alignment `c`. Only thing that could be hard to get is the long arrows in the top row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Version without Ti*k*Z and only `tabular`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ccellcolor}{HTML}{d09000}

\newcommand*\revealcline{\noalign{\vskip\arrayrulewidth}}
\newcommand*\nextrow[1]
  {\\\cline{#1}\noalign{\vskip1ex}\cline{#1}\revealcline}
\newcount\ccellA
\newcommand*\ccell[2]
  {%
    \def\tmpa{}%
    \ccellA=1
    \loop
      \ifnum#1=\ccellA
        \edef\tmpa{\unexpanded\expandafter{\tmpa\cellcolor{ccellcolor}}}%
      \fi
    \ifnum#2>\ccellA
      \advance\ccellA1
      \edef\tmpa{\unexpanded\expandafter{\tmpa&}}%
    \repeat
    \tmpa
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[c]{l *5{|p{2em}}|}
  & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{$\longleftarrow$ Total Number of Dataset $\longrightarrow$}\\
  \cline{2-6}\revealcline
  Experiment 1 & \ccell{1}{5}
  \nextrow{2-6}
  Experiment 2 & \ccell{2}{5}
  \nextrow{2-6}
  Experiment 3 & \ccell{3}{5}
  \nextrow{2-6}
  Experiment 4 & \ccell{4}{5}
  \nextrow{2-6}
  Experiment 5 & \ccell{5}{5}\\
  \cline{2-6}
\end{tabular}\hskip1em
\begin{tabular}[c]{|p{2em}|l}
  \cline{1-1}
  \ccell{0}{1}  & Training
  \nextrow{1-1}
  \ccell{1}{1}  & Validation\\
  \cline{1-1}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Today is 1<sup>st</sup> of May, so I don't have to work and I'll draw it for you ;)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (M) [matrix of nodes,
        nodes={minimum height = 7mm, minimum width = 2cm, outer sep=0, anchor=center, draw},
        column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}, minimum width = 4cm},
        row sep=1mm, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, nodes in empty cells,
        e/.style={fill=yellow!10}
      ]
      {
        Experiment 1 & |[e]| & & & & \\
        Experiment 2 & & |[e]| & & & \\
        Experiment 3 & & & |[e]| & & \\
        Experiment 4 & & & & |[e]| & \\
        Experiment 5 & & & & & |[e]| \\
      };
      \draw (M-1-2.north west) ++(0,2mm) coordinate (LT) edge[|<->|, >= latex] node[above]{Total number of datasets} (LT-|M-1-6.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is `edge[|<->|` something new? Never saw it before --> very handy

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner No it is not new and it is used everywhere in the manual.

Comment: Good to know. Will be useful in the future. Thanks for the reply.