# Create a Tikz Matrix with Segments of Solid and Dashed Borders

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, diagrams

I examined the post below which has an answer to create a matrix which consists of solid borders for each cell:

[k-Fold cross-validation figure using TikZ or table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429451/k-fold-cross-validation-figure-using-tikz-or-table)

The answer that was chosen to be correct creates the following picture:

[image]

Is it possible to modify this code inorder to obtain a picture where some segments of the horizontal borders are dashes instead of solid lines.

By this I mean whether it is possible to obtain a pictures such as the one below?

[image]

I have attempted to play with the anchors and the parameters in the matrix however I have not been successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `dashed` to node options.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (M) [matrix of nodes,
        nodes={minimum height = 7mm, minimum width = 2cm, outer sep=0, anchor=center, draw},
        column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}, minimum width = 4cm},
        row sep=1mm, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, nodes in empty cells,
        e/.style={fill=yellow!10},
        a/.style={dashed},
      ]
      {
        Experiment 1 & |[e]| & & |[a]| & & \\
        Experiment 2 & & |[e]| & |[a]| & & \\
        Experiment 3 & & & |[e, a]| & & \\
        Experiment 4 & & & |[a]| & |[e]| & \\
        Experiment 5 & & & |[a]| & & |[e]| \\
      };
      \draw (M-1-2.north west) ++(0,2mm) coordinate (LT) edge[|<->|, >= latex] node[above]{Total number of datasets} (LT-|M-1-6.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```